# importing store to a vuejs nuxt project

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to write a simple plugin for my Vue.js(Nuxt) project. I came across this post [Adding Mutations to Vuex store as part of Vue Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45644171/adding-mutations-to-vuex-store-as-part-of-vue-plugin) but still unable to get it working.

Here is my application structure.

```
~ is root

~/plugins/HTTP/index.js
~/plugins/HTTP/_store/ => index.js, actions.js, getters.js, mutations.js
~/plugins/HTTP/_api/ => index.js

**Global Store**
~/store/index.js
~/store/modules/
~/store/modules/testing => index.js, actions.js, getters.js, mutations.js
```

in my `~/plugins/HTTP/index.js`, I have the following code

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import store from '~/store';

const HTTP = {
    install(vue, { store }){ // Now you plugin depend on store
        if(!store){
            throw new Error('Please provide vuex plugin.')
        }
        // register your own vuex module
        store.registerModule({store})
    }
}

export default HTTP;

Vue.use(HTTP)
```

In my `~/store/index.js` I have the following code:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import testingModule from './modules/testing'

const state = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    modules:{
      testing: testingModule
    }
  })
}

export default state
```

When I try to run it, it gives me the following message:

```
Cannot destructure property `store` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
```

What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing any properties so the error is correct. You need pass in an `options` object when you tell it to `use`. It can be empty, but it needs an object.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import store from '~/store';

const HTTP = {
    install(vue, { store }){ // Now you plugin depend on store
        if(!store){
            throw new Error('Please provide vuex plugin.')
        }
        // register your own vuex module
        store.registerModule({store})
    }
}

export default HTTP;

Vue.use(HTTP, {}) // <---------- Empty object to avoid allow destructuring.
```